# Unable to resolve .. resolve waits for ever while building red5 using ant and ivy

Tags: java, ant, ubuntu, red5, ivy

I am following step by step for installation of RED5 in Ubuntu 9.04.
While executing ant command, it waits forever at

```
[ivy:resolve] :: resolving dependencies :: red5#server;working@satya-vbox4red5
[ivy:resolve]  confs: [java6]
```

in verbose mode, I saw that it is failing while searching for dependencies..
verbose output can be found at http://pastebin.com/uyaQ03cK

I am accessing the internet through a proxy server which asks for authentication(userid and password).

Answer (score 1):

Try configuring ANT to use the proxy:

```
<setproxy proxyhost="${proxy.host}" proxyport="${proxy.port}" proxyuser="${proxy.user}" proxypassword="${proxy.pass}"/>
```