# RED5 installation

Tags: java, red5

Please, i need help with this...I need red5 to put on server, but i did'n go near that step.
I fallow some tutorials on web, and i use this steps:

1. install jdk(i have it allready)

2.install ant (same)

3.put variable path

4.create folder and then i use SVN Checkout on it

5.downloaded last version of red5 from trunk

6.i opened project in eclipse and then when eclipse build it and now i have over 5000 errors

7.when i go to command promt and go to my folder where i downloaded red5 and type ant dist it starts to build, but it never finises, because it stops at resolving with ivy

This is output from cmd:

```
D:\Eclipse\Projects\Red5Server>ant dist
Buildfile: D:\Eclipse\Projects\Red5Server\build.xml

-library.check:
     [echo] Java: java.home is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\jre and the tar
get version is 1.6
     [echo] Ant: ant.home is C:\apache-ant-1.8.2 and the target version is Apach
e Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010

-java6.check:
     [echo] Using Java 1.6 specification: 1.6

prepare:

compile:
     [echo] javac version: 1.6
     [echo] Not using the Eclipse IDE
     [echo] Compiler adapter name: modern

compile-core:

retrieve:
     [echo] Ivy conf name: java6
[ivy:resolve] :: Ivy 2.2.0 - 20100923230623 :: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ ::
[ivy:resolve] :: loading settings :: file = D:\Eclipse\Projects\Red5Server\ivyse
ttings.xml
[ivy:resolve] :: resolving dependencies :: red5#server;working@Jovan-PC [not tra
nsitive]
[ivy:resolve]   confs: [java6]
```

I'm really grateful for help!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651028/unable-to-successfully-install-installation-hangs-while-building-red5-using-a   --> im guessing that IVY is trying to connect to sources and failing. Try it with the 'verbose mode'.. also make sure to 'make clean' after the big fail with eclipse.. and that eclipse isn't locking any folders  - close it before trying via cmd line.

Comment: Thanks for your response...can you explaine it more because this is my first time with ant and building from console... And when i open red5 project (what i downloaded from google) it displays over 5 000 errors...is this normal?

Comment: That's probably just the missing dependencies. You need to get ivy to run properly before this will compile.

Comment: When you installed ivy it should have created the 'hello-ivy' demo. Try that and see if its happy. http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/tutorial/start.html   I would also go through the list of modules that Red5 is trying to dl and make sure you can get to those locations directly.

Comment: hi Jovan, .  I hope your problem got resolved otherwise try again after installing ivy.install apache ivy (http://ant.apache.org/ivy/). E:\dev\red5\java\server\trunk>ant ivyclear dist   This will make your build successful

Answer (score 1):

Red5-1.0.0-RC2
http://www.filewatcher.com/m/red5-1.0.0-RC2.tar.gz.44088464-0.html

Installation RED5
Download red5-1.0.0-RC2.tar.gz from above link
extract it
Download 
Embed RED5 with eclipse 
Create aaplication

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Try Using Netbeans and Glassfish:

Red5 can be installed as stand alone server or as a war deployment.

The procedure is to create war deployment of red5 version 0.8(old version). (Lengthy, please bear with me).

Download and install jdk1.6, glassfish2.1 and netbeans 6.5 on linux.

Download "Red5War_0.8.0.war".

I am sharing in the hope that the following may help the community to create a deployable war red5 version 0.8 on glassfish2.1 by following the steps using in Netbeans 6.5:

Step 1: Un-zip the Red5War_0.8.0.war

Step 2: Create a web project named "red5" in Netbeans

Step 3: Copy the content of "/WEB-INF/classes" of inflated war folder and paste it in "Source Packages" of Netbeans Project.

Step 4: Right Click "Libraries", add "JAR/Folder", navigate to "/WEB-INF/lib" of inflated war folder, select all the dependency jars and Click On "Open" of Netbeans Project.

Step 5: Delete WEB-INF of Netbeans Project (Note : Ignore Warning/Error).

Step 6: Delete META-INF of the inflated folder.

Step 7: Copy the remaining content ("/WEB-INF/classes" and "/WEB-INF/lib") of the inflated folder to "Web Pages" of Netbeans Project.

Step 8: Open the following ports in the firewall TCP/843,TCP/1935,TCP/5229,TCP/5080

Step 9: Run the project

Step 10: Deployable war file "red.war" is created in the Netbeans Project Folder(../NetBeansProjects/red5/dist/)

Please share your findings in creating new version(1.0, 1.0.1, 1.02) war deployments  using new version netbeans, jdk on new version glassfish server(3.x).

Best wishes!

Arumugam A.V